# IntelliJ: Classes from imported jar not visible inside packages

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I added external jar file(`stdlib.jar` on picture) to my project in IntelliJ(12.1.4), but when I want to use some static methods from it in created **package**(`ChapterOne`) it can't resolve it. ***However it finds classes in default package without problem***. How I can make it work ?

[image]

It seems that dependencies are ok.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to add the jars to the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm not sure, but I think dependencies were ok. I updated with image.

Comment: On your first screenshot `External Libraries` node has nothing under it, while on the second screen it can be expanded, so it looks like you've added the libraries to the dependencies on the second screenshot, but at the time the first screenshot was taken the libraries were not added.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I've just checked and under External libs there is only  `< 1.7 >` which points to jdk.

Comment: Double click on the libraries to see that they have correct jars added.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm not sure what exactly you wanted me to click, but I expanded 1.7 and there are some jars, but not any of mine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35022/discussion-between-ashur-and-crazycoder)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The libraries were configured correctly in IDEA, but the jars actually contained sources, not classes. So the solution is to unpack these sources from the jar files into the module `src` directory.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I checked the jar, they contain both .class and .java files. If I create class in default package, I can use classes from the jar, otherwise - no.