# Importing jars in intellij not working

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

[Importing jar file into IntelliJ Idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051991/importing-jar-file-into-intellij-idea)

[IntelliJ: Classes from imported jar not visible inside packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111277/intellij-classes-from-imported-jar-not-visible-inside-packages)

I have seen similar questions without a solution. I have these jar's with source and class files which I have added to my project and they do turn up. However they are not visible inside the package. I am new to this intellij and can't figure out what's wrong.

[image]

Comment: Try Alt+Enter ( quick help ) I think that should fix your issue.

Comment: How will that fix my issue ?  it suggest's me to create those classses.

Comment: I am also new to jars. What is the expected structure of these jar files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't actually a problem with intelliJ, you are fighting against the java spec: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package

Place the classes into a package and try `<alt><enter>` on the red word.

Alternatively, do not place your code into a package, just put it in the default package.

Comment: I am a Java noob. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I would just like to say that you should never use the default package if you can avoid it. In this case, you can't especially as IIRC the online grader requires the default package.

Answer (score 0):

File → Project Structure (CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + S on Windows/Linux, ⌘ + ; on Mac OS X) → Module → Dependencies → Add... → Project Library → Attach Jar

Comment: It's already added as you can see the arrow keys against the external Libraries.  I tried module, project library, global library. It seems to get added but I still get the cannot resolve symbol error.

Answer (score -2):

I see you're on the Algorithms class, I've been in that spot too.
Check this answer out though:

[IntelliJ: Classes from imported jar not visible inside packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111277/intellij-classes-from-imported-jar-not-visible-inside-packages?lq=1)

It says you're suppose to:

1. Add the ".jar" as libraries into your "Project Structure".
2. Create a new package in your "src" directory.
3. COPY and PASTE the classes you want into your newly created package.
4. DONE.

Voila, now you should be able to use the objects inside!

Hope that helps!